# Rotation of an object around its local axis

Tags: python, scripting, bones

I've been trying for a while now to rotate a rig around its local axis.

Given 3 angles I would like to rotate the bone around its axis.
I saw that in the UI method that is used [`bpy.ops.transform.rotate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.rotate) method, however this method has an argument called orientation matrix which I'm not sure how to calculate.

Does anyone know how I am supposed to calculate this arg?

Comment: Are you trying to rotate an object or a bone in pose mode?

Answer (score 1):

This argument is **optional** ; but if you really want to deal with **linear transformation matrices**, you have to understand how it works.

You could use `matrices` in order to compute `translation`, `scale` and `rotation`.

Here, the matrix is a **rotational matrix**, which expect some value according to the axis you choose given an angle `t` (aka `theta`) :

- for the x axis, the matrix will be
  `(( 1, 0, 0), (0, cos(t), sin(t), (0, -sin(t), cos(t))`
- for the y axis, the matrix will be
  `(( cos(t), 0, -sin(t) ), (0, 1, 0), (sin(t), 0, cos(t))`
- and for the z axis, you will have `((cos(t), sin(t), 0), (-sin(t), cos(t), 0 ), (0, 0, 1))`

If you select the default cube, you can see its transformation matrix:

```
>>> obj = bpy.context.active_object
>>> obj.matrix_world
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Now, you can use a `mathutils.Matrix` in order to rotate the object to 20° on the `X` axis:

```
>>> rotation_mat = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(20), 4, 'X')
>>> obj.matrix_world @= rotation_mat
```

> I use the `@=` python operator that provide a matrix multiplication

**Does anyone know how I am supposed to calculate this arg ?**

Now you know how to calculate this arg ; but not how to use it !
The way [bpy.ops.transform.rotate](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.rotate) use the `orient_matrix` argument is not clear ; it seems to have no effect here, because you have to provide the mandatory 1st argument which set the angle value and do the same thing. With the `Blender Python API`, Some parameters are historical, some others for future use, and some others are not implemented at all but still documented. You could ask the team because I tried many way to use it without any effect.

Last but not least, playing with Maths is really easy if you read the right book: [3D Math Primer for Game Dev - Fletcher Dunn - 2cd Ed.- 2011](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/_/X3hmuhBoFF0C?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA2aj6g-D4AhXNgv0HHep7AtIQre8FegQIERAG) is definitively the best book for anybody having to play with math without any skills. You will find 3 chapters on Matrices, very well explained.